# Give value based on multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is my first question on SO...please be nice. :)

I have a data.table with multiple columns being boolean. I now want to create a new column that depends on which of the boolean columns is true.

I.e.

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(F,T,F), b = c(F,F,F), c = c(F,F,T), d = c(F,F,F))
DT
       a     b     c     d
1: FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE     
2:  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3: FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The result should be something like:

```
DT
       a     b     c     d  new column
1: FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE      "none"
2:  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  "column a"
3: FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  "column c"
```

Imagine there are many columns so that nested ifelse statements are not really feasible. There are also columns in the original data table which are not boolean and that should not be modified.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Here is one option `DT[, new_column := names(.SD)[max.col(.SD, "first") * NA^!Reduce('+', .SD)]]`

Comment: Took me a while to figure out whats happening...didn't think of max.col. Thanks :)